# Parallelize for loop in bash

Tags: bash, parallel-processing, gnu-parallel

I have the following snippet in my bash script

```
#!/bin/bash
    for ((i=100; i>=70; i--))
      do
        convert test.png -quality "$i" -sampling-factor 1x1 test_libjpeg_q"$i".jpg
      done
```

How can i execute the for loop in parallel using all cpu cores.I have seen `gnu parallel` being used but here i need  the output filename in a specific naming scheme as shown above

Comment: turn your `convert ..` line into a separate shell script that `parallel` can call . Good luck.

Comment: Append a blank and `&` to convert command.

Comment: Note that, if performance is your primary concern, and depending on the ratio of the sizes of each image to the total number of images, it may be better to use `mogrify` and **GNU Parallel**'s `-X` option because if you use `convert`, you necessarily have to create a whole new process for every image. So if you have a large number of small images, the overhead is enormous. Say you have 80,000 images, you will be better off with 8 `mogrify` processes doing 10,000 images each, than 80,000 `convert` processes doing 1 each.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `parallel` like this:

```
parallel \
'convert test.png -quality {} -sampling-factor 1x1 test_libjpeg_q{}.jpg' ::: {100..70}
```

Comment: ' and " are unneeded.

Comment: Yes not needed in this example but a good practice in general.

Comment: Yes, if we are talking shell variables. No if we are talking GNU Parallel substitution strings: `echo 'a  b' | parallel 'echo "{}"'` This is because GNU Parallel quotes the string by default.